# Passing multiple parameters from controller to factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing three parameters from my controller to the factory following way.

In my controller I am trying to pass three parameters id,sdt and edt ..

```
 $scope.val = function () {
        $scope.tech = techRepository.getTech.query({ id: $scope.id, sdt: $scope.sDate, edt: $scope.eDate }, function(data) {
            scope.tech = data;
        });
    };
```

In my factory I have

```
App.factory('techRepository', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
       getTech: $resource('/api/Tech/GetRange/:id', {id: '@id', start: '@sdt', end: '@edt'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray:true}})
    };
}]);
```

When I run this I get Bad Request error. Please let me know how to pass multiple parameters. Thanks

Comment: See the network call in browser debugger console. See what parameters are being send you may get some idea about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine, presuming you want `:id` in your query string to be replaced with the value of `$scope.id`, and two query parameters (`sdt` and `edt`) attached like:

```
http://www.example.com/api/Tech/GetRange/123?edt=20140610&sdt=20140609
```

It seems like you may instead be expecting a URL that looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/api/Tech/GetRange/123?end=20140610&start=20140609
```

... in which case, your code should look like:

```
// in controller
$scope.val = function () {
    $scope.tech = techRepository.getTech.query({ id: $scope.id, start: $scope.sDate, end: $scope.eDate }, function(data) {
        scope.tech = data;
    });
};

.factory('techRepository', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getTech: $resource('/:id', {id: '@id'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray:true}})
    };
}]);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6T4mgCYA3Q3ZJSa4fOC?p=preview)